# Multiple Precision Zero verify in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to compare a signed number N with 32 bits against zero and against other 32 signed number. How can I do it?

Suppose that N32 is on DX:AX.
I was trying to do to compare against zero:

```
sub ax,0
sbb dx,0
jz
;do else
```

But here I was compare only MSByte (dx), isn't it?

To compare against another number. Supposing in memory referenced by SI:

```
sub ax,[si]
sbb dx,[si+2]
jz
;do else
```

And here we have the same problem.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two 16-bit quantities in memory or register and you want to test if they are both zero you can `OR` them together.  If the result of the `OR` is zero, then both operands were zero.

If you have two 32-bit quantities each represented as two 16-bit quantities and you want to know if the two 32-bit quantities compare equal, then subtract the upper 16-bits of the two quantities and the lower 16-bits of the two quantities and `OR` those differences together... again, if the result of the `OR` is zero, then both 32-bit quantities were equal.

Let's say you have a 32-bit quantity in DX:AX and another in CX:BX and you want to know if they are equal:

```
sub ax,bx ; ax = ax - bx
sub dx,cx ; dx = dx - cx
or  ax,dx ; ax = ax OR dx
je  they_are_equal
```

The `SUB` can be replaced with `XOR`:

```
xor ax,bx ; ax = ax ^ bx
xor dx,cx ; dx = dx ^ cx
or  ax,dx ; ax = ax OR dx
je  they_are_equal
```